# SSRS - Calendar Report Query

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, ssrs-2008-r2, outer-join

I'm making a calendar-style report similar to [this](http://msdyn.blogspot.com/2013/07/create-calendar-style-reports-in-sql.html). But my query isn't returning what I need it to. I'm using a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` on a Date table but I also need to filter the results by a `JobID`. When I do this, it obviously only returns the results with the `JobID`. I feel like I'm missing something simple here...any help would be appreciated!

**Original Query:**

```
SELECT  t1.[TimeSheetLineID] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetID] ,
        t1.[JobID] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetDate] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetCreatedOn] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetLastModifiedOn] ,
        t1.[StartTime] ,
        t1.[EndTime] ,
        t1.[TotalTime] ,
        t1.[EmployeeName] ,
        t2.[FullYear] ,
        t2.[WeekNumber] ,
        t2.[WeekDay] ,
        t2.[WeekDayName] ,
        t2.[MonthDay] ,
        t2.[MonthName] ,
        t2.[MonthNumber]
FROM    [dbo].[FactTimeSheets] t1
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.DateLookup t2 ON t1.TimeSheetDate = t2.DateFull
WHERE (t1.JobID = @jobNumber) AND (t2.FullYear = @year) AND (t2.MonthNumber BETWEEN @startMonth AND @endMonth)
ORDER BY FullYear, MonthNumber, MonthDay, WeekDay
```

**Results I'm getting from above query:**
[image]

**Second Query, gives me all dates needed but not filtered by JobID:**

```
SELECT  t1.[TimeSheetLineID] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetID] ,
        t1.[JobID] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetDate] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetCreatedOn] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetLastModifiedOn] ,
        t1.[StartTime] ,
        t1.[EndTime] ,
        t1.[TotalTime] ,
        t1.[EmployeeName] ,
        t2.[FullYear] ,
        t2.[WeekNumber] ,
        t2.[WeekDay] ,
        t2.[WeekDayName] ,
        t2.[MonthDay] ,
        t2.[MonthName] ,
        t2.[MonthNumber]
FROM    [dbo].[FactTimeSheets] t1
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.DateLookup t2 ON t1.TimeSheetDate = t2.DateFull
WHERE (t2.FullYear = @year) AND (t2.MonthNumber BETWEEN @startMonth AND @endMonth)
ORDER BY FullYear, MonthNumber, MonthDay, WeekDay
```

**Results I expect to see (JobID filter taken out...but I need it):**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reversing it... Also, if you put conditions on your outer-joined table in the where clause, it will act like an inner

```
SELECT  t1.[TimeSheetLineID] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetID] ,
        t1.[JobID] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetDate] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetCreatedOn] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetLastModifiedOn] ,
        t1.[StartTime] ,
        t1.[EndTime] ,
        t1.[TotalTime] ,
        t1.[EmployeeName] ,
        t2.[FullYear] ,
        t2.[WeekNumber] ,
        t2.[WeekDay] ,
        t2.[WeekDayName] ,
        t2.[MonthDay] ,
        t2.[MonthName] ,
        t2.[MonthNumber]
FROM    dbo.DateLookup t2
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[FactTimeSheets] t1 
  ON t1.TimeSheetDate = t2.DateFull
  AND (t1.JobID = @jobNumber) 
WHERE (t2.FullYear = @year) 
  AND (t2.MonthNumber BETWEEN @startMonth AND @endMonth)
ORDER BY FullYear, MonthNumber, MonthDay, WeekDay
```

Comment: That will get closer to the solution, however, I am afraid the query above will leave gaps in the calendar where there is no data for a given calendar day for the given job.

Comment: @RossBush How so?

Comment: Doh! my bad. For some reason I had the table reversed in my mind.